# How to make chrome screen size is myscreen size while i am using inspect?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, mozilla, web-inspector

I attached two screenshots both Mozilla and chrome
[image: Mozilla Browser Screeenshot]
[image: Chrome Browser Screenshot]

While I am using **Inspect element** control Mozilla was viewed as  my actual screen size but chrome changed in different  resolution

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]Activate responsive web design mode in FF (CTRL+SHIFT+M)

In chrome, disable device mode, to get the normal screen size.

Comment: No i m not asking this @pravid

Comment: In chrome you have responsive mode active. Disable it to get the normal screen size then. See the attachment.

Answer (score 2):

There is a button in the inspect element in Chrome to *toggle device toolbar*.
Click it, and you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you've opened the inspector, click on the kebab menu on the top right(three vertical dots), there select the doc size to "undock into separate window".